# How can I get Open NFC + NFC Simulator + Ubuntu + Android Emulator + VirtualBox/Wine working?

Tags: android, nfc

I'm trying to develop NFC based apps for Android by using the Open NFC stack and its various tools, mainly its NFC Simulator in Ubuntu 11.10.

The problem with trying to use the NFC Simulator is that it is mainly meant for Win32 environments. Since the NFC Simulator uses the Connection Center tool which aids in remote connections, I simply virtualized WinXP and ran the tools after installing its basic requirements. The tools seem to run fine on the guest OS.

When I emulate the Android provided by the Open NFC add-on image, I'm unable to connect to the connection center by providing the IP address.

Basically, the emulator is unable to connect to the local network.

1. How do I connect to any service/server that is running on a different machine from the emulator?
2. I tried running it on Wine; it actually connected, but did not completely register. Any help with that?

Comment: Welcome to Android Stack Exchange. Android Enthusiasts - Stack Exchange is for enthusiasts, power users, and regular people who use the Android operating system. Developing/programming for Android are off-topic here, please ask these questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It looks like you haven't configured the virtual networking in VirtualBox so that you can't connect to your guest via IP. See the [relevant section](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) in the documentation for VirtualBox.

Comment: @mindcorrosive I have been using Vbox for a while now and i've tried ALL possible combinations of the network adapter, but in none of them have i been able to access the guest via IP from the emulator. Can you tell me how to do it?